# No retrofit annotation found #1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-volley, retrofit, retrofit2

i am trying to make a post request using retrofit 2.0 which also has image to be sent but everytime i try i get an error saying no retrofit annotation found .. please help me out in resolving this issue ...will be very thankful.. following below is my code snippet

MY RETROFIT INTERFACE

```
 @Multipart
    @POST("empowerapp/seekerreg.php")
    Call<ResponseModel> registerSeeker(@Part MultipartBody.Part image,
                                       @Part("fname") RequestBody fname,
                                       @Part("fname") RequestBody lname,
                                       @Part("promoter") RequestBody promoter,
                                       @Part("dob") RequestBody dob,
                                       @Part("gender") RequestBody gender,
                                       @Part("paswd") RequestBody paswd,
                                       @Part("ph") RequestBody phone,
                                       @Part("email") RequestBody email,
                                       @Part("weight") RequestBody weight,
                                       @Part("height") RequestBody height,
                                       @Part("qualification") RequestBody qualification,
                                       @Part("color") RequestBody color,
                                       @Part("lang_known") RequestBody languages,
                                       @Part("experience") RequestBody experience,
                                       @Part("exp_type") RequestBody exptype,
                                       @Part("dres_code") RequestBody dresscode,
                                       @Part("vehicle_mode") RequestBody vehicleMode,
                                       @Part("photo1") RequestBody photo1,
                                       @Part("photo2") RequestBody photo2,
                                       @Part("photo3") RequestBody photo3,
                                       @Part("address") RequestBody address,
                                       @Part("landmark") RequestBody landmark,
                                       @Part("location") RequestBody location,
                                       @Part("city") RequestBody city,
                                       @Part("state") RequestBody state,
                                       @Part("contry") RequestBody contry,
                                       @Part("pincode") RequestBody pincode,
                                       @Part("bank_name") RequestBody bankName,
                                       @Part("ac_name") RequestBody acName,
                                       @Part("ac_number") RequestBody acNumber,
                                       @Part("ifsc") RequestBody ifsc,
                                       @Part("br_name") RequestBody brName,
                                       @Part("size") RequestBody size);
```

MY RETROFIT CALL METHOD

```
public void registerSeeker(SeekerProfileModel profileModel) {

        System.out.println("###exp" + s_exp.getText().toString());

        //create file which we want to send to server.
        File imageFIle = new File(selectedIdproofPath);

        //request body is used to attach file.
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),imageFIle);

        //and request body and file name using multipart.
        MultipartBody.Part selectedIdproof = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("id_proof", imageFIle.getName(),requestBody); //"image" is parameter for photo in API.


        RequestBody promoter = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),profileModel.getPromoter() );
        RequestBody fname = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),profileModel.getFname());
        RequestBody lname = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),profileModel.getLname());
        RequestBody email = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getEmail());
        RequestBody phone = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getPhone());
        RequestBody languages = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getLanguages());
        RequestBody address = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getAddress());
        RequestBody landmark = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),profileModel.getLandmark());
        RequestBody city = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"),profileModel.getCity());
        RequestBody state = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getState());
        RequestBody contry = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getContry());
        RequestBody pincode = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getPincode());
        RequestBody paswd = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getPassword());
        RequestBody dob = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getDob());
        RequestBody gender = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getGender());

        RequestBody exp = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getExperience());
        RequestBody weight = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getWeight());
        RequestBody expType = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getExperienceType());
        RequestBody qualification = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getQualification());
        RequestBody color = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getColor());

        RequestBody size = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getSize());
        RequestBody height = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getHeight());
        RequestBody dresscode = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getDressCode());
        RequestBody vehicleMode = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getVehicleMode());
        RequestBody photo1 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getPhoto1());
        RequestBody photo2 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getPhoto2());
        RequestBody photo3 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getPhoto3());
        RequestBody bankname = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getBankName());
        RequestBody branchname = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getBranchName());
        RequestBody acccountnumber = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getAccontNumber());
        RequestBody ifsc = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getIfsc());
        RequestBody accountholder = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), profileModel.getAccountName());

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Allconstants.MAIN_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

        RetrofitInterface service = retrofit.create(RetrofitInterface.class);

        Call<ResponseModel> call = service.registerSeeker(selectedIdproof,fname,lname,promoter,dob,gender,paswd,phone,email,weight,height,qualification,color,languages,exp,expType,dresscode,vehicleMode,photo1,photo2,photo3,address,landmark,landmark,city,state,contry,pincode,bankname,accountholder,acccountnumber,ifsc,branchname,size
                );
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Response<ResponseModel> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
                System.out.println("###coming" + response.body().getStatus());
                pd.dismiss();
                if (response.body().getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("Success"))
                {
                    pd.dismiss();
                    loginSession.createLoginSession(Allconstants.SEEKER,Allconstants.S_REG_ACTIVITY,response.body().getName(), response.body().getId());
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"successfully registered",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    System.out.println("###coming"+response.body().toString());
                }else{
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(Registration.this,"oops!!!something went wrong..try again"+response.body().getStatus(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
                pd.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(Registration.this, t.getStackTrace().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                System.out.println("###error1" + t.getMessage());
                System.out.println("###stack trace: ");
                t.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: You've probably imported the wrong `@POST` annotation, thus no "retrofit" annotation being present. Check your imports

Comment: i have imported right postt annotation

Comment: post full error please

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process: mufeez.com.empower, PID: 22345 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1) for method RetrofitInterface.registerSeeker –

Answer (score 0):

For the first parameter ,

examine this code

```
File file = new File(filePath);

RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), file);

MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("upload",file.getName(), reqFile);
```

you had this `MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data")` try the above.You need to use file providers,To securely offer a file from your app to another app, you need to configure your app to offer a secure handle to the file, in the form of a content URI. The Android FileProvider component generates content URIs for files, based on specifications you provide in XML.

Defining a FileProvider for your app requires an entry in your manifest. This entry specifies the authority to use in generating content URIs, as well as the name of an XML file that specifies the directories your app can share.

```
 String mCurrentPhotoPath;

 private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
// Create an image file name
String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new  Date());
String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
File storageDir = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
File image = File.createTempFile(
    imageFileName,  /* prefix */
    ".jpg",         /* suffix */
    storageDir      /* directory */
);

// Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();
return image;
```

}

then call that  function exposing the file to fileprovider to get a path.

```
    Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this,
                                              "com.example.android.fileprovider", image /* return file*/);
```

Comment: or CTRL + Enter i think

Comment: also your constructor is pretty big, trace and make sure their identically placed.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: mufeez.com.empower, PID: 22345
                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #1)
                                                                        for method RetrofitInterface.registerSeeker

Comment: i dont understand where am i going wrong .... its been from morning i am stucked ... please help me

Comment: i am certainly certain you are uploading a image, then use the above multipart body type.

Comment: did you change this "multipart/form-data" alone right

Comment: wait, that selectedIdproofPath could be the culprit, where are you getting it , gallery or capture

Comment: using it from capture     Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
        selectedIdproofPath = getRealPathFromURI(selectedImageUri);

Comment: public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri uri) {
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }

Comment: wait you should be using a file provider for captured images that is wrong.please read this, i was making the same mistake util i understood this tutu rial,https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html. The problem is the uri itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139645/discussion-between-caspain-caldion-and-md-gouse).

Comment: where do i use this method createimagefile ? and how? please help me